# Manipulate JSON node to have [] parentheses

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

Json response from 3rd party platform which I cant control.

```
$json = '{
  "question1": "answera",
  "question2": [
       "answerb",
       "answerc"]
}';
```

Any 'question' can have multiple 'answers', however if there is only one 'answer' for that question the response comes back without the [] parentheses - this is breaking the insert into the next system (that I also dont have control over) as it is expecting the [].

Using PHP is there a way to manipulate the json string to be the following, irrelevant of the number of 'answers':

```
"question1": ["answera"],
```

Comment: Sure, just decode the JSON, check each question property and see if it's an array or not, and if not, then get the data from it, put it into an array, and set the property to that new array. Then encode back to JSON again.

Comment: P.S. I sympathise, I hate APIs etc which output inconsistently formatted data.

Comment: Inconsistent data is the hell for developers.

Comment: Thank you Both.  Indeed!! Im using a iPaSS tool that should be able to do point and click integrations however little inconsistencies like this are really throwing it off..... Hopefully can fix with that php helper function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert string contents into an array. But you habe to iterate over all answers for this purpose.

### Creating an array with an if-condition

```
<?php
$json = '{
  "question1": "answera",
  "question2": [
       "answerb",
       "answerc"
  ]
}';

// second parameter for array result
$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($array as $question => $answer) {
    if (is_string($answer) === true) {
        $array[$question] = [ $answer ];
    }
}
```

This one results into ...

```
array(2) {
  'question1' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "answera"
  }
  'question2' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "answerb"
    [1] =>
    string(7) "answerc"
  }
}
```

For any further JSON processing you can convert the PHP array back into JSON.

```
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Results into ...

```
string(109) "{
    "question1": [
        "answera"
    ],
    "question2": [
        "answerb",
        "answerc"
    ]
}"
```

### Casting with (array)

Another solution taken from the comments was mentioned by [@RickN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316310/rickn). Casting with `(array)` avoids the if condition and could possibly be faster, if that matters for your application.

```
foreach ($array as $question => $answer) {
    $array[$question] = (array) $answer;
}
```

Comment: You could also just cast the value: `$array[$question] = (array)$answer`. `(array)$answer` on a string creates an array with that string in it. If it's already an array `(array)$answer` does nothing.

Comment: Thanks @RickN for this solution. Added it to the answer as possibly more performant possibility to solve the issue.